# What angle of ascent did the LEM use to leave the moon?

Tags: apollo-program

I've been playing around with lunar launch delta-v requirements, and it seems that you can get a lot of bang for your buck if you launch "sideways" so to speak. Well, in the absence of atmosphere obviously... But I'd see that as a huge safety hazard to the crew if a certain threshold was exceeded. I wouldn't want to be flying 100 meters above the surface of the moon flying at 100m/s.

Does anyone have a diagram of the LEM ascent trajectory that illustrates the maneuver used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [mission planning document](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/nasa-tnd-6846pt.1.pdf) has such a diagram.

The TL;DR: ascend straight up for 8-10 seconds, then execute a gradual tipover from vertical to horizontal over the remainder of the ascent, approximating [a linear-tangent steering law](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/29792/195).

The expected trajectory parameters are given in the LM timeline documents such as [this one for Apollo 12](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a12/a12lm-timeline.pdf) (the page labeled FLIGHT PLAN ASCENT MONITOR); I haven't checked to see how they compare to the linear tangent law results.

Comment: The angle of the flight path! Right, that's the word I was looking for. Thanks for the linked documentation.

Comment: I'm still trying to find an authoritative description of the actual guidance program, i.e. whether it was computing arctangents or just working through a table. Might have to get one of our AGC program analysts involved...

Comment: If you'd like, feel free, this more than answers the intended scope of the question though; I'd say this is a duplicate unless you'd like me to edit it to include more about the ascent guidance program (which I absolutely would love to see!) If you do talk to someone I'll make appropriate edits to conform the topic more towards the guidance methodologies and choices made by the computer

Comment: Toss-up whether it's dupe or not; I'm going to write a separate question asking about the implementation details.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, I'll accept that and vote to close, let everyone else decide. Link that question though, I'll +1 and follow it :).

Comment: https://space.stackexchange.com/q/31196/195