# Rocket Launch Simulation Source Code Locations

Tags: launch, rockets, simulation, simulator

As you can take from the title, does anyone know where I could find the source code for a working launch simulation type application such as FlightClub for example?

Comment: The problem with an accurate rocket launch simulation is that such a simulation would also serve as an accurate missile launch simulation. That in turn means you can't find such a thing on the internet. It's classified or ITAR.

Comment: That's an extreme use case.

Comment: Related: [How does Flight Club simulate Falcon 9 launches?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/30914/195)

Answer (score 2):

Searching “launch simulation github” will probably lead you to a number of options. I found https://github.com/jcreus/launchsim to be a very useful reference and starting point when I was working on my (currently closed source) launch simulation. While it's basic, it includes a simple atmospheric drag model and specific impulse increasing with altitude, but it doesn't model body lift and assumes attitude changes are instantaneously and perfectly executed.

Comment: Is this complete? While I have very little knowledge of Python, it does not look all there.

Comment: It’s somewhat minimal, by no means equivalent to Flight Club, but a good simple starting point.

Comment: I am mainly trying to find alternatives to compare with my attempted simulator. The complexity of working with altitude, pressure, drag, lift and all the others is quite tough without comparison examples.

Comment: My 'is it complete' comment is really in relation to your example one not having that type of complexity

Comment: While I do not know the extent of your search, you'd be surprised at how little realistic rocket simulators with the code available there actually are.

Comment: The sim I linked does model air pressure by altitude, and has a simple drag model, but doesn't do lift.

Comment: You say you've got your own. Has your launch simulator ever 'suffered' with getting different results to other launch simulators with the same rocket stats? Based on about 5 other launch simulators, they all seem to get roughly the same result, but mine always seems to act differently.

Comment: I only really compared mine with Robert Braeunig's Saturn V sim -- which has gone 404, possibly for ITAR compliance, but is archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170313142729/http://www.braeunig.us/apollo/saturnV.htm) -- and got agreement close enough for my purposes, which are not critical. Where and how does your sim start to diverge from Flight Club?

Comment: @RussellBorogove may I inquire as to why you wanted to create a personal-purpose launch simulator :)? Also, do you think the question, "What have space-affiliated employees programmed in their free time? Has it ever contributed to a funded mission or scientific discovery? Were they compensated afterwards?" is a good question? I've seen tons of answers about team-related accomplishments, wondering if solo accomplishments (like amateur astronomy) can lend itself to furthering space exploration.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn May I inquire if you work for the State Department? ;) ...actually, mostly for fun, some to help answer questions on this site (e.g. [optimal lunar ascent](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/29625/195) ), some to develop background for stories about an alien species' space age.

Comment: @RussellBorogove now I want to know more about **your** projects than I want to ask that question hah! But I may still ask it. I've been very interested in what type of person makes a space-faring human (and what they'd be interested in with their free time) ever since I saw Don Petit at NEAF and NEAIC. Also, no-sir, I do not work for any government agency ;).

Comment: @RussellBorogove My simulation just provides different results and it could be literally anything. Due to a lack of understanding to why it does what it does and how I could go about fixing it, the extreme frustration it causes continues to leave it unfinished. Coded entirely in JavaScript and being about 300 lines long, I regret ever starting it in a way, so I'd not be bothered about making it.

Comment: I worked on the Shuttle Mission Simulator. Without knowledge of the details of your simulation, it would be difficult to offer detailed advice. But you could attempt to determine where yours first starts to diverge from the others, and see what is the dominant effect at that point.